# Is there a Stack Exchange for the business side of mobile development?

Tags: discussion, site-rec

I'm interested in asking questions in regards to admob/iads/iap/freemium/revenue/etc for mobile/desktop app desktop. Basically business type of questions. I'm wondering if there's a stack exchange for mobile business development, or do those questions happen here?

Answer (score 2):

I believe your best option would likely be looking at http://freelancing.stackexchange.com (help center: [on topic](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)) or http://startups.stackexchange.com (help center: [on topic](https://startups.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)) depending on the topic of question.